# Help understanding this tweet

Tags: meaning

For reference the text comes from the following [tweet](https://twitter.com/SCA_DI/status/1345772095192530949)

My understanding of the context is that this person and someone else(referred to as 作画サイド in the tweet) had a work adapted into an anime that they weren't too happy about how it went. Essentially they (the anime studio / director / etc) ignored the original creators and they replaced lots of the jokes/parodies etc.

I've highlighted the bit in bold that I'm looking for help with.

> ちなみに世代的にパロディのネタはボクは分かったけど作画サイドは「全然知らん。分からん」状態で何度か **「原作差し止めしてでもあの内容はやめてほしい」言われもても「まぁまぁ」といった結果が今なので、世の中「大人に対応」って言われるもんはその場凌ぎの無策って事だけは学びましたな** 。

It's split into two parts:

「原作差し止めしてでもあの内容はやめてほしい」言われもても「まぁまぁ」といった結果が今なので - My understanding of this is that someone was asked by the artist to stop this "content"(referring to what is happening to the anime) even if it meant stopping the original work, and they responded telling the person to calm down. Who was the person who told them this, it sounds like it was someone other than the author of the tweet but I'm not sure.

世の中「大人に対応」って言われるもんはその場凌ぎの無策　- The thing called "adult response" is just a temporary/stopgap measure. Would anyone be able to provide more understanding in what they mean by this phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this 某アニメ refers to [this](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%81%88%E3%81%B3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%93%20%E5%85%AC%E7%AB%8B%E6%B5%B7%E8%80%81%E6%A0%96%E5%B7%9D%E9%AB%98%E6%A0%A1%E5%A4%A9%E6%82%B6%E9%83%A8), which was full of parodies from old anime in the 80s and 90s. 原作(者) refers to the tweet author (すかぢ) himself.

> 何度か 「原作差し止めしてでもあの内容はやめてほしい」言われもても
> I've been told several times "Stop those (weird parodies) even if that means using your power as the original author", but...

言われもても is a typo for 言われてても. This 原作差し止めする means 原作者としての権力を使って(アニメの内容を)差し止める, not 原作を差し止める. Of course the point of those tweets is that the 原作者 had no such power.

> 「まぁまぁ」といった
> things went like "Calm down"...

I think it's best to interpret this といった as not "I said ～" nor "They said ～" but as "It went like ～". The author probably wanted to say `「まあまあ」という感じになった` but it was truncated a bit oddly because it was a tweet.

> 結果が今
> ...and the consequence is this (what we can see now).

Grammatically, 結果 is modified by a long relative clause (何度か～といった).

> なので、世の中「大人に対応」って言われるもんはその場凌ぎの無策って事だけは学びましたな。
> So I at least learnt that so-called 大人の対応 is just a stopgap measure.

大人の対応 is "handling matters maturely". It implies someone in the 委員会 said "Let's be more mature about this" to him, and he realized it just meant "Please do nothing, please don't complicate things now".